# как получить доступ из MainActivity к элементам из другого layout файла?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть виджет, который должен выползать снизу при нажатии кнопки, в нем находятся чекбоксы с которыми мне нужно работать уже в основной активности из метода `onCreate`, если я пытаюсь их хоть как то затронуть, например повесить слушатель на чекбокс, то получаю ошибку вида:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yar.myapplication/com.yar.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.yar.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckBox checkBox;

BottomSheetDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


}

public void showBottomSheetDialog(View view) {
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog, null);
    dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="131dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="showBottomSheetDialog"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_sheet_dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CheckBox" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

не пойму, как правильно объявить чекбоксы, чтобы с ними можно было работать из главной активности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае получайте доступ к чекбоксам в самом методе `showBottomSheetDialog` через `view`, например:

```
public void showBottomSheetDialog(View view) {
view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog, null);

// Получаем доступ к вью элементам
Checkbox checkbox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: мне нужно обрабатывать события чекбоксов из метода onCreate, забыл упомянуть, то бишь к примеру у меня есть listview и в зависимости от того выбран чекбокс или нет, я в слушателе на списке делаю то или иное действие

Comment: Создайте метод в `MainActivity` и вызывайте его в `showBottomSheetDialog` в слушателе `Checkbox`a.

Comment: ладно, переделал немного проект и поставил вызов диалога по нажатию на итем листа, связи с чем надобность в чекбоксах пропала, но все равно спасибо за ответ

Comment: Ну вы можете сохранять состояние чекбоксов в `SharedPreferences`, а в методе `onClick` вашего `ListView` получать сохраненные значения и сделать условие, например `if (checkboxOneIsChecked) {//Делать то-то} else {//Делать то-то}`